# Can't use elasticsearch search_analyzer in kibana discover

Tags: elasticsearch

This is the index i created with analyzer setting.I understand the concept of index time analysis and search time analysis.

```
PUT test-index-000001
{
   "settings":{
     "number_of_replicas": 0, 
      "analysis":{
         "analyzer":{
            "autocomplete":{ 
               "type":"custom",
               "tokenizer":"standard",
               "filter":["lowercase","autocomplete_filter"]
               }
         },
         "filter": {
           "autocomplete_filter":
           {
             "type": "edge_ngram",
             "min_gram": 1,
             "max_gram": 20
           }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings":{
       "properties":{
          "title": {
             "type":"text",
             "analyzer":"autocomplete"
              
             }
      }
   }
}
```

Then i add one document in it.

```
PUT test-index-000001/_doc/1
{
   "title":"Quick Brown"
}
```

After then i search "Qui" in kibana's discover my query is matched , i search again but this time i search for "quick br" and my search match again. Although i should not match because i am not using search_analyzer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [`search_analyzer` docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html)

> By default, queries will use the analyzer defined in the field
> mapping, but this can be overridden with the search_analyzer setting.

When using the same index mapping, as given in the question above, the following tokens are generated for the "Quick brown"

```
GET <index-name>/_analyze
{
  "text": "Quick Brown",
  "analyzer": "autocomplete"
}
```

Following tokens are generated :

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "q",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 5,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "qu",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 5,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "qui",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 5,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "quic",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 5,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "quick",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 5,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "b",
      "start_offset" : 6,
      "end_offset" : 11,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "br",
      "start_offset" : 6,
      "end_offset" : 11,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "bro",
      "start_offset" : 6,
      "end_offset" : 11,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "brow",
      "start_offset" : 6,
      "end_offset" : 11,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "brown",
      "start_offset" : 6,
      "end_offset" : 11,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Therefore, when you are searching for `quick br`, using Kibana, you are getting the document in return.